# Customizing url encoding scheme for python requests library

Tags: python, google-maps, python-requests

I'm trying to use my Google Maps API for Business license, and I've been using the python requests library for previous code, and I want to continue to use it for my google maps API calls.

However, I'm having a problem where the signature URL parameter I generate always ends with an equal sign (=), and that gets URL-encoded as '%3D'. Any way I can override this encoding rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Advanced Usage - Prepared Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests).

You can prepare a request and manipulate it before sending it. In your case, you'd prepare the  request without signature and append it to the `url` attribute of the `PreparedRequest` object.